# JavaScript: ReferenceError: homeLoanForm is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on some homework with a lot of predefined code.  When I run my code, so far, FireBug throws up a *"ReferenceError: homeLoanForm is not defined."*  I'm not sure what's going on, especially since I didn't write most of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Chapter 10 Shoreline State Bank</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Hide from old browsers -->
    var adMsg = " ** Did you know some used cars can have 100% loan value? Ask for details! ** "
    var beginPos = 0
    function scrollingMsg() {
        msgForm.scrollingMsg.value = adMsg.substring(beginPos, adMsg.length)+adMsg.substring(0, beginPos)
        beginPos=beginPos+1
        if (beginPos>adMsg.length) {
            beginPos=0
        }
        window.setTimeout("scrollingMsg()",200)
    }

    var salesAmt
    var loanAmt
    var loanRate
    var loanYears

    function validSalesAmt() {
        var salesAmt=parseInt(homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.value,10)
        if (isNaN(salesAmt) || (salesAmt <= 0)) {
            alert("The sales price is not a valid number!")
            homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.value = ""
            homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.focus()
        }
        else {
            var downPmtAmt=parseInt(homeLoanForm.DownPayment.value,10)
            if (isNaN(downPmtAmt) || (downPmtAmt <= 0) || (downPmtAmt > salesAmt)) {
                alert("The down payment should be greater than 0 and less than the sales amount!")
                homeLoanForm.DownPayment.value = ""
                homeLoanForm.DownPayment.focus()
            }
            else{
                loanAmt = salesAmt-downPmtAmt
                homeLoanForm.LoanAmount.value = loanAmt
                homeLoanForm.Rate.focus()
            }
        }
    }

    function CalcLoanAmt() {
        loanRate=parseFloat(homeLoanForm.Rate.value)
        if (isNaN(loanRate) || (loanRate <= 0)) {
            alert("The interest rate is not a valid number!")
            homeLoanForm.Rate.value = ""
            homeLoanForm.Rate.focus()
        }
        else {
            loanYears=homeLoanForm.Years.value
            if  (isNaN(loanYears) || (loanYears < 1 || loanYears > 30)) {
                alert("Please select a valid number from the list (10, 15, 20, or 30)!")
                homeLoanForm.Years.selectedIndex = 0
                homeLoanForm.Years.focus()
            }
        }
    }

    //-->
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .align-center {
        text-align:center;
    }

    table {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 70%;
    }

    .block {
        width: 50%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .center-div {
        width: 70%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .header-text {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .center-items {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .right-align {
        text-align: right;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .left-align {
        text-align: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    #displayDateLast {
        text-align: left;
        width: 50%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="scrollingMsg();">
    <div class="center-div">
      <p class="center-items"><img src="chapter10-1banner.jpg" alt="banner" /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="center-div">
    <form id="msgForm">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><input type="text" name="scrollingMsg" size="25" /></p>
    </p>
    </div>
    <p style="text-align:center; font-size:16; font-weight:bold;">Home Mortgage Loan Payment Calculator</p>
    <p class="block"><strong>Directions: </strong>Enter the agreed selling price, press the tab key, enter the down payment and press the tab key. The loan amount will be calculated automatically. Then enter the interest rate and the number of years for the loan and click the Calculate button.</p>
    <div class="center-div">
    <form id="homeLoanForm" method="post">
      <table>
            <tr>
               <td class="right-align">
                  <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Sales Price:
               </td>
               <td class="align-left"><input type="text" name="SaleAmount" size="9" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="right-align">
                 <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Down Payment in Dollars
              </td>
              <td class="align-left"><input name="DownPayment" type="text" id="DownPayment" size="9" onblur="validSalesAmt()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="right-align">
                 <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Loan Amount
              </td>
                 <td class="align-left"><input name="LoanAmount" type="text" id="LoanAmount" size="9" />          
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="right-align">
                  <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Interest Rate (e.g. 5.9):
              </td>
               <td class="align-left"><input name="Rate" type="text" id="Rate" size="5" maxlength="5" /> 
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="right-align">
                  <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Number of Years:
               </td>
               <td><select name="Years" id="Years">
                 <option value="0">Select Number of Years</option>
                 <option value=10>10</option>
                 <option value=15>15</option>
                 <option value=20>20</option>
                 <option value=30>30</option>
               </select></td> 
          </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="right-align">
                 <input name="button" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="CalcLoanAmt()" />
               </td>
               <td class="align-left">
                 <input name="Reset" type="reset" />
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="right-align">
                  <span style="font-weight:bolder;">Monthly Payment:</span>
               </td>
               <td><input type="text" name="Payment" id="Payment" value=" " size="12" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="align-center">
                 <span style="color:#cc0000; font-size:12px;">* Indicates a required field.</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear your variable `homeLoanForm` has not had a value set for it. You need to walk through your code and find out what that variable should reference and then make sure you have the code that assigns that value to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you never defined the variable `homeLoanForm` in your code.

Assuming that it should refer to your form with the same id, make sure to define it before using it, e.g.:

```
var homeLoanForm = document.getElementById('homeLoanForm');
```

Comment: Well, I put that code in, but now it's saying homeLoanForm is null

Comment: Your scripts need to go after your HTML. It will be null at first, but if your scripts are after the HTML it will not be null.

Answer (score 0):

I added a variable to homeLoanForm. Should work now.

```js
var homeLoanForm = document.getElementById('homeLoanForm');
var adMsg = " ** Did you know some used cars can have 100% loan value? Ask for details! ** "
    var beginPos = 0
    function scrollingMsg() {
        msgForm.scrollingMsg.value = adMsg.substring(beginPos, adMsg.length)+adMsg.substring(0, beginPos)
        beginPos=beginPos+1
        if (beginPos>adMsg.length) {
            beginPos=0
        }
        window.setTimeout("scrollingMsg()",200)
    }

    var salesAmt
    var loanAmt
    var loanRate
    var loanYears

    function validSalesAmt() {
        var salesAmt=parseInt(homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.value,10)
        if (isNaN(salesAmt) || (salesAmt <= 0)) {
            alert("The sales price is not a valid number!")
            homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.value = ""
            homeLoanForm.SaleAmount.focus()
        }
        else {
            var downPmtAmt=parseInt(homeLoanForm.DownPayment.value,10)
            if (isNaN(downPmtAmt) || (downPmtAmt <= 0) || (downPmtAmt > salesAmt)) {
                alert("The down payment should be greater than 0 and less than the sales amount!")
                homeLoanForm.DownPayment.value = ""
                homeLoanForm.DownPayment.focus()
            }
            else{
                loanAmt = salesAmt-downPmtAmt
                homeLoanForm.LoanAmount.value = loanAmt
                homeLoanForm.Rate.focus()
            }
        }
    }

    function CalcLoanAmt() {
        loanRate=parseFloat(homeLoanForm.Rate.value)
        if (isNaN(loanRate) || (loanRate <= 0)) {
            alert("The interest rate is not a valid number!")
            homeLoanForm.Rate.value = ""
            homeLoanForm.Rate.focus()
        }
        else {
            loanYears=homeLoanForm.Years.value
            if  (isNaN(loanYears) || (loanYears < 1 || loanYears > 30)) {
                alert("Please select a valid number from the list (10, 15, 20, or 30)!")
                homeLoanForm.Years.selectedIndex = 0
                homeLoanForm.Years.focus()
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.align-center {
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        table {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 70%;
        }
        
        .block {
            width: 50%;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
        
        .center-div {
            width: 70%;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
        
        .header-text {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .center-items {
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .right-align {
            text-align: right;
            width: 50%;
        }
        
        .left-align {
            text-align: left;
            width: 50%;
        }
        
        #displayDateLast {
            text-align: left;
            width: 50%;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chapter 10 Shoreline State Bank</title>
</head>

<body onload="scrollingMsg();">
    <div class="center-div">
        <p class="center-items"><img src="chapter10-1banner.jpg" alt="banner" /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="center-div">
        <form id="msgForm">
            <p style="text-align: center;"><input type="text" name="scrollingMsg" size="25" /></p>
            </p>
    </div>
    <p style="text-align:center; font-size:16; font-weight:bold;">Home Mortgage Loan Payment Calculator</p>
    <p class="block"><strong>Directions: </strong>Enter the agreed selling price, press the tab key, enter the down payment and press the
        tab key. The loan amount will be calculated automatically. Then enter the interest rate and the number of years for
        the loan and click the Calculate button.</p>
    <div class="center-div">
        <form id="homeLoanForm" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right-align">
                        <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Sales Price:
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left"><input type="text" name="SaleAmount" size="9" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right-align">
                        <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Down Payment in Dollars
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left"><input name="DownPayment" type="text" id="DownPayment" size="9" onblur="validSalesAmt()" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right-align">
                        <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Loan Amount
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left"><input name="LoanAmount" type="text" id="LoanAmount" size="9" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right-align">
                        <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Interest Rate (e.g. 5.9):
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left"><input name="Rate" type="text" id="Rate" size="5" maxlength="5" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right-align">
                        <span style="color:#cc0000;">*</span>Number of Years:
                    </td>
                    <td><select name="Years" id="Years">
                 <option value="0">Select Number of Years</option>
                 <option value=10>10</option>
                 <option value=15>15</option>
                 <option value=20>20</option>
                 <option value=30>30</option>
               </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right-align">
                        <input name="button" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="CalcLoanAmt()" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left">
                        <input name="Reset" type="reset" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="right-align">
                        <span style="font-weight:bolder;">Monthly Payment:</span>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Payment" id="Payment" value=" " size="12" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="align-center">
                        <span style="color:#cc0000; font-size:12px;">* Indicates a required field.</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```